# Extract string from HTML tags using RegExp (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, regex, html-parsing

I would like to extract "toast" from a string `<h1>test</h1><div>toast</div>`. What regular expression could isolate such a string?

Edit: Thanks to the user who who corrected the formatting.

More Info: There will always only be one instance of the div tag, the information inside may change but there will never be another div tag in the same string (the string is larger than the given sample)

Thanks!

Comment: based on what? do you just want all text within any div? this is probably best to do with some sort of dom parser rather than regex.

Comment: @smerny sorry, I fixed the question. My boss is requiring me to use regex, so I have no choice :/

Comment: `Nokogiri` is the best tool to parse the HTML and XML stuffs..

Comment: We need more information. Which part of the string is variable? For example, a naive solution could be `regex = /<h1>test<\/h1><div>([^<]*)<\/div>/`

Comment: Well, this is just a small part of the entire string so no easy solutions work unfortunately (I tried those, but the regex is way too clunky). All the tags will always remain the same, it's the content inside (i.e. "toast") that will change

Comment: Is there always only a single div within this string? More context is needed to give an accurate answer.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/ruby for examples of how to properly parse HTML with Ruby modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions summons Zalgo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/38765

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really not something that is typically done with regex... and for a good reason, but if you must and since you said there will never be more than a single div within it... this should work for you:

```
(?<=<div>).*(?=</div>)
```

Comment: This isolates the correct information (toast) but I have one question - If i wanted to return it, what would I have to use on the string? I tried string.split(/(?<=<div>).*(?=<\/div>)/) and string.scan(/(?<=<div>).*(?=<\/div>)/) but neither are correct.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Nokogiri`](http://nokogiri.org/).

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse("<div> test </div> <div> toast </div>")
doc.css('div').map(&:text)
# => [" test ", " toast "]
```

---

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse("<h1>test</h1><div>toast</div>")
doc.at_css('div').text
# => "toast"
```

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the question. This shouldn't be that complicated, right?

Comment: Using an HTML parser is not complicated.  Dealing with changes in your data that you don't expect, but are still perfectly valid HTML, is what is complicated.  A little time spent up front with a proper HTML parser will save you hours of debugging and heartache down the road.

Answer (score 1):

We need more information. If the string is exactly `"<h1>test</h1><div>toast</div>"`, then something naïve like

```
regex = /<h1>test<\/h1><div>([^<]*)<\/div>/
found = "<h1>test</h1><div>toast</div>".match(regex)[1]
# => "toast"
```

would work. My best guess at this point is that you are expecting

```
<h1>*</h1><div>*</div>
```

then use this:

```
regex = /<h1>[^<]*<\/h1><div>([^<]*)<\/div>/
found = "<h1>any string can go here</h1><div>toast</div>".match(regex)[1]
# => "toast"
```

Note that this breaks if there are any nested elements in either tag. A more robust solution is to use Nokogiri. Talk to your boss.